# Checkboxes and setting their default checked values from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database table called artist_genres. I currently have a function which finds all genre_id's by artist and echo's them in an object oriented way:

```
<?php
$artistgenres = Artistgenres::find_all_genres_by_artist_id($_SESSION['artist_id']);
foreach($artistgenres as $artistgenre){
  echo $artistgenre->genre_id."<br>";
}
?>
```

[image]

When the artist with id 8 logs in, and goes to this page, I would like for him to be able to update the current genre_ids associated with them.

The form data looks like:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="Genres[]" value="2">Classical</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="Genres[]" value="3">Hiphop</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="Genres[]" value="4">Jazz</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" id="grad" value="Login" />
</form>
```

So effectively, for the classical example, what I want to achieve is to look up and find all genre_id, see if the value 2 is in the list of genre_ids, if so change the markup to:

```
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="Genres[]" value="2"<? php if(somecondition = 2) {echo "checked"} ?> >Classical</label>
```

However, I'm having a hard time putting this into code. Can you help me out?

Comment: a ternary operator is usually best for this. A bit tricky but well worth it, believe me.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a bunch of variables and then asking if $variable1 = 2 OR $variable1 = 2 .... and so on for all, but it seems very messy. Could you give me an example of the ternary operator?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I understand that I need some sort of condition $artistgenre->genre_id == 2  ? echo "checked" : echo""; The problem is that $artistgenre->genre_id comes from the loop, and has 3 instances above (from the table for artist_id=8)

Comment: You should probably query the `genre` table that has the `id, name` of the genre with a JOIN in the query. Then the setting of the checkboxes would be far more obvious to you

Comment: RiggsFolly I can do SELECT genre_name FROM genres WHERE id=2, but I don't see where it would get me. I'm just left with names instead of id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all of the selected genres of the user in an array:

```
$selectedgenres = array();
foreach($artistgenres as $artistgenre){
    $selectedgenres[] = $artistgenre->genre_id;
}
```

List all genres as checkboxes (I assume you have a separate table for all of your genres). Then use `in_array()` to check each genre if it is part of the selected genres by the user:

```
foreach(your condition here for getting all genres){

?>    
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="Genres[]" value="<?=($genreid)?>"><?=($genredesc)? <?php echo (in_array($genreid, $selectedgenres))?' checked':''; ?>></label>
    </div>

<?php

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need. However, I don't understand the value="<?=($genreid)?>"><?=($genredesc)? <?php echo (in_array($genreid, $selectedgenres))?' checked':''; ?>> part. What is $genredesc? I tried to do the following: <label><input type="checkbox" name="Genres[]" value="2" <?php echo (in_array(2, $selectedgenres))?' checked':''; ?> >Classical</label>, but I get an error: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\MAMP\htdocs\grnew\public\demotest.php on line 44

Comment: @GRS - You have to replace those variables according to how you fetch your data. `$genreid` means `genre_id` column and `$genredesc` for the `genre_description` column on your `genre` table. And for the error, `$selectedgenres` should be an array, see my answer on how I made it to an array.

Comment: I think it's complaining that number 2 is not an array, not that $selectedgenres is not at array

Comment: I made an error by defining it at the bottom, instead of begining of code. It seems to be working fine now. Thanks a lot!